# About learning fibre product

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request

When I was reading Hartshorne's book, I find I was very unfamiliar with fibre product of schemes. I don't know what it looks like after glueing affine pieces. It looks so strange! (Both the topology space and its sheaf)

Can you tell me some materials about it?(like the book's name) I want to read more about it to learn it!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I just need some books  in which they say something about fibre product for me to get familiar with fibre product. Just give me the books' name. Thanks a lot!

Comment: try The Geometry of Schemes by Eisenbud and Harris.

Comment: Thank you, hunter. I will try!